# How to have multi layouts in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am beginner in yii2, there are two page in my project, one for public user and one for registered users. Now how can i have two layouts in layouts folder and how can i to render in controller?

Comment: Did you read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create all the layout you want in view/layout  ..

You can set the layout in controller .

```
public function actionEvent()
{
    $this->layout = 'you_layout';

   return $this->render('event' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```